# Meshlab doesn't visualize face of a triangle, ply format wrong?

Tags: graphics, meshlab

I have this file:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 3
property float32 x
property float32 y
property float32 z
element faces 1
property list uint8 int32 vertex_indices
end_header
0.075 1.44 1.42483
0.075 1.45483 1.41
0.0601702 1.44 1.41
3 0 1 2
```

But when I run meshlab I can only see three points and not the face connecting them, is my file content wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is called `face` and not `faces`:

```
element face 1
```